# Empty Windows Home Group unremovable and lost password

Tags: windows, homegroup

i had a Home Group set up between several Windows 7 PC's until i upgraded one to Windows 10 and the home group had connection problems. I tried to remove the Home Group and removed every PC from it manually. Now all the PC's including the Windows 10 PC think there is a join-able Home Group from witch i don't know the password, and since it's without member PC's i cannot recover the password from the current one.

How do i get rid of this ghost Home Group?

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I get rid of this ghost Home Group?

> 1. Remove ALL machines from homegroup
> 2. Turn ALL machines off
> 3. Turn one machine on
> 4. Create a new homegroup on that machine
> 5. Turn on others one by one and join them to it

Source [WIN 10 Homegroup issues](http://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/win-10-homegroup-issues/)

Comment: Did everything already until step 3, but i CANT create a new Homegroup on any machine since all the machines somehow think there still is a homegroup.

Comment: @Jeroen Read this thread, there are a couple of other suggestions in it [Phantom HomeGroup: Need to delete HomeGroup from a PC that no longer exists](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/phantom-homegroup-need-to-delete-homegroup-from-a/28f494ea-d0e9-4aeb-8e32-20f0942d1f11)

Comment: Thnx for the tip, but that article also does not provide an other solution but to rollback or reinstall computers. Microsoft needs to change it's security policy around Homegroups, enabling admins to make more "Homegroup master" computers in the HomeGroup or always give a Slave pc a final "that's it, im outta here" solution to exit a Homegroup so a non-existing-but-still-active Homegroup can haunt in our memory (pun intended).

Comment: That article is useless. I had read it and tried its suggestions unsuccessfully before finding this question.